# What adapter is used to implement a lengthy dynamic layout that is not repetitive like a Listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

for ex:
in zomato app for the list of restaurants we use `listview` or `recyclerview` with custom `arrayadapter` or `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

but the Zomato restaurant profile page is lengthy and has a lot of info that changes with each restaurant input data.
So, what adapter is used to dynamically write data to this page?
Or is there any other concept that I don't know of.

[image: image for reference, zomato profile page]

Comment: You can use `uiautomatorviewer` or Android Studio's layout inspector and find out for yourself. There is nothing stopping that from being a `ListView` or a `RecyclerView`. Or, it could be a `LinearLayout` wrapped in a `ScrollView`. For all I know, it is a `WebView`.

Comment: To know the how they did, If you have application in your device, go to Developer Options >> **Show layout bounds** ( Enable it ). There you go you can see how the layout is created

Comment: If you did't find any layout bounds in that screen. then it is WebView as @CommonsWare said.

Comment: so, how do i do it with a listview? enclose entire layout in a single list item?